# a Prince Charming, a rock, a man with whom... -- what do they mean by "a rock"?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

Source: [‘That terrorist is not your Prince Charming!’: Cosmo warns Russian women against ISIS temptation](https://www.rt.com/news/323708-cosmo-isis-recruitment-jihad/)

> “A woman who is lonely or dissatisfied in her personal relationship is the ideal candidate for recruitment,” says the article, arranged in a helpful question and answer format. “All of a sudden fate will bring… a Prince Charming, **a rock**, a man with whom you can build a solid and happy future. This is not how it will actually work out.”

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> rock
>
> NOUN
>
> 3. used in similes and metaphors to refer to someone or something that is extremely strong, reliable, or hard

As stated after the comma: *a man with whom you can build a solid and happy future.*

Modern homes are built on a *foundation*. First a big hole is dug in the ground, then it is leveled off, and a foundation is built using concrete. The home is then build upon this concrete foundation.

*Rock* is being used as a synonym for **Foundation**.

Answer (score 3):

The original [article](http://www.cosmo.ru/lifestyle/society/kak-terroristy-igil-verbuyut-zhenshchin-v-seti/) uses a Russian saying "как за каменной стеной", literally "like behind a rock wall", which refers to a husband as strong, reliable, and safe as a fortress wall.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a reference to the biblical metaphor of [building one's house on a rock](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%207%3A24-27&version=NKJV).

> "a wise man who built his house on the rock: and the rain descended, the floods came, and the winds blew and beat on that house; and it did not fall, for it was founded on the rock.

-- Matthew 7:24-25, NKJV